# How can you imagine a photon?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, quantum-electrodynamics, virtual-particles

Is it correct to imagine a photon as a superposition of states <photon + virtual electron-positron pair + virtual quark + antiquark + ...> pair? And the lower the photon energy, the lower the amplitude of the virtual terms?

Comment: In case, does it really helps? :)

Comment: @Alchimista do not understand

Comment: Me either :) it was a joke. Normally we imagine something that reconducts or has analogue in the world as we sense. If it would have been "treat" instead of "imagine" I wouldn't have spot it. I personally cannot imagine a quark *image* if I can *image* a virtual one in superposition with a photon, plus..... I can't really *image* any of them :)

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your question involves the distinction between "dressed" and "free" photons, right?

Comment: @Nihar Karve right.

Comment: The question seems to attract answers about the shape or the particle-like properties of a photon. But as far as I understand, the point is whether the electric field of the photon creates virtual dipoles from charged particle-antiparticle pairs.

Comment: @A.P.You understand correctly. And the question is more about whether the photon does this constantly and all the time, or only from time to time. As I understand it, he does it constantly and all the time.

Answer (score 3):

In mainstream physics a photon is part of the elementary particle table which is axiomatically assumed in creating the quantum field theory [standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model). The photon as all the particles is a point particle, of zero mass, and in QFT is created by creation operators acting on the photon field. The photon field, the electron field etc are quantum fields postulated over all spacetime, represented by the plane wave wave function of the corresponding differential equations: Dirac for fermions, Klein Gordon .... For photons it is the [quantized Maxwell equation.](http://cds.cern.ch/record/944002?ln=en) .

This for interactin photons.A free photon cannot be described by a plane wave since a plane wave wavefunction  covers all spacetime. One uses the [wave packet](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/wpack.html) mathematics, so a free photon instead of having a unique frequency will have a probability distribution of many frequencies in the wave packet.

In no way a different model as you suggest, fits the observed data and behavior of a photon.

Comment: Have you seen the exact photon propagator?

Comment: And it seems to me that you are confused. A free photon with a certain momentum is described precisely as a plane wave, and a wave packet is obtained from the superposition of many such plane waves, if it is necessary to approximately localize the photon. But a description of the interaction without a perturbative theory is impossible.

Comment: @ArmanArmenpress  have I not stated that the standard model is a quantum theoretical model. And the photon is an elementary particle,, not a propagator, which is the the mathematical expression used in the mathematics of QFT to model a *virtual photon*. Virtual photons are not real on mass shell particles, they are mathematical constructs,  to help keep count of conservation of quantum numbers and energy momentum, in each term ot the perturbative expansion. You cannot localize a free photon of one frequency, its probability to be seen  is all over space time

Comment: . The photon propagator describes a real photon, look at the diagrams.
https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/One-loop-structure-of-the-photon-propagator-in-the-Hern%C3%A1ndez-Ju%C3%A1rez-Monta%C3%B1o/b8274c300e006d7eb62f37fef9fe8643 figure / 1
There is an incoming and outgoing line. And virtual processes are the result of vacuum polarization.

Comment: The link you give does not work. Look at the second page  here http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html .Real are the particles described by a four vector which has a length equal to the invariant mass  of the particle. Only incomoing and outgoing particles are real , by construction of QFT

Comment: The photon interacts with other fields all the time, and these virtual loops are a way of describing this interaction.

Comment: If there is no incoming and outgoing energy, the loops are virtual, and in any case the electromagnetic coupling constant is so small that even the higher order corrections they represent  are very small

Comment: In this case, the incoming and outgoing lines are present.

Comment: which case? the link you gave does not work

Comment: if you mean a running line of a real  photon with loops, the loops have zero energy, which means they are off mass shell (the electron andpositron on masss shellneed 1 mev

Comment: They can have any energy. Off-mass shell means that the relationship between momentum and energy is not met. And the energy of virtual particles can be any. As far as I understand, you are an experimenter and have not gone deep into theory.

Comment: " energy of virtual particles can be any" within the limits of integration . Yes, experiments define what physics is, modeling measurements with mathematical theories. It helps not to confuse physics with mathematics.  I think this discussion should be over.

Answer (score 0):

One should never think of a photon in terms of a "point-like particle", as it's neither point-like nor particle. First it is delocalised, any attempt to prescribe it a position is **not** Lorentz invariant, therefor since you cannot give a unique position in all reference frames we can't speak of point-like. This misuse of terminology comes from the fact that  measurement(the act of absorption) occurs at a specified point.
It is also not a particle, this interpretation streams from scattering experiments where the momentum transfer imitates particle scattering, from which one can conclude that the photon is as much of a particle as your strawberry ice cream is a strawberry fruit.
It is a quasi-partice, with all the mysticism this word brings, it can take different quantum states, can interfere, can tunnel, etc. Upon imagining a photon, one should define it properly, is it the object deduced from the equations with energy "

ℏ
ω

"
or the object that makes the detector clicks, as the two are not the same. I personally imagine the second since no source produces the first. The frequency cannot be defined by infinite precision, as in the real world no source has infinitely short lifetime, which brings us to the point that we always have a spread of frequencies(although small). This philosophical gymnastics makes me think of it as a collection of EM waves with a spread of 
Δω
, that can "sense" each other, which is the property of coherence. In my opinion this ontological interpretation of the photon is much closer to the object that Roy Glauber [**describes**](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.131.2766), consistent with Lamb Jr.'s criticism of the [**terminology**](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01135846) and much closer to what the empirical reality suggests.

Comment: *any attempt to prescribe it a position is not Lorentz invariant*  --- the same is of course true of point-like particles, so I don't see what this has to do with the assertion that a photon is not a point-like particle.

Answer (score -2):

In simple imagination Photon is the packet of energy. The rest mass of Photon is zero, having energy E= hv(nu) , where is planks constant. Photon is moving with the velocity of light.